# Time Limit Exceed for BFS algorithm

Tags: python, breadth-first-search, time-limiting

It is leetcode #200, number of islands.
My code is

```py
def numIslands(self, grid: List[List[str]]) -> int:
        def bfs(i,j):
            q = deque([[i,j]])
            while q:
                r,c = q.popleft()
                if 0<=r<len(grid) and 0<=c<len(grid[0]) and grid[r][c]=="1":
                    grid[r][c]="0"
                    q += [[r + 1, c], [r - 1, c], [r, c - 1], [r, c + 1]]
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            for j in range(len(grid[0])):
                if grid[i][j]=="1":
                    count+=1
                    bfs(i,j)

        return count
```

It works fine.
But when I change the `bfs` function into

```
def bfs(i,j):
    q = deque([[i,j]])
    while q:
        r,c = q.popleft()
        grid[r][c]="0"
        for d in [[r + 1, c], [r - 1, c], [r, c - 1], [r, c + 1]]:
            if 0<=d[0]<len(grid) and 0<=d[1]<len(grid[0]) and grid[d[0]][d[1]]=="1":
                q.append(d)
```

It gives me the Time Limit Exceeded error, what could the reasons be?
I think these two codes are nearly identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are visiting the same state many times:

Change to the following:

```
def bfs(i,j):
    q = deque([[i,j]])
    grid[i][j]="0"

    while q:
        r,c = q.popleft()
        for d in [[r + 1, c], [r - 1, c], [r, c - 1], [r, c + 1]]:
            if 0<=d[0]<len(grid) and 0<=d[1]<len(grid[0]) and grid[d[0]][d[1]]=="1":
                grid[d[0]][d[1]]="0"
                q.append(d)
```